# Trying to delete source file/ reading file after reading it and writing to new file

Tags: javascript, java, io

I am trying to delete source file which is used for reading. But Delete part is not working. I used code but when I compile it skip to else part

```
public class delete{
      public static void main (String[] args){
          BufferedReader br=null;
          BufferedWriter bw= null;

         String outFileName= "C:\\Users\\dokania\\Desktop\\New folder\\out.txt";
         File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\dokania\\Desktop\\New folder\\casp10.txt");

          try{
              String s;
              int fileCounter=0;
              FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outFileName);  
                          bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                  br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));

                    while ((s=br.readLine())!= null){
                      bw.write(s +"\n");                      
                  }
                  boolean success = (new File (file1.getName())).delete();
        if (success)
                  {
                      System.out.println(file1.getName()+ "file isdeleted");
                  }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(file1.getName()+ "file not deleted");
                }
          }catch(IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
           }
         finally{
             try{
                 if(br!=null){
                     br.close();
                   bw.close();
                 }
             }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              } 
         }

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    String outFileName = "C:\\Users\\dokania\\Desktop\\New folder\\out.txt";
    File file1 = new File("C:\Users\dokania\Desktop\New folder\casp10.txt");

    try {

        String s;

        int fileCounter = 0;

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outFileName);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

            bw.write(s + "\n");

        }
        br.close();

        if (file1.delete()) {
            System.out.println(file1.getName() + " is deleted!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {

            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code it is perfectly working for me.i think just try to refresh the project folder where you keep your files and just use single escape sequence for both file path location

Comment: Thanks for help. In my code I had forgotton to close my reading file before delete operation. above code and comment helped me to understand my missing point.